# Helm lookup function dynamically fetch value from a configmap

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am attempting to use the Helm [lookup](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function) function to dynamically lookup a key `ORGANIZATION_NAME` from a ConfigMap and use that value.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: celery-beat
  labels:
    app: celery-beat
    tags.datadoghq.com/env: {{ (lookup "v1" "configmap" "default" "api-env").items.ORGANIZATION_NAME | quote }}
    ...
```

But I am getting the error:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: template: celery-beat/templates/deployment.yaml:9:66: executing "celery-beat/templates/deployment.yaml" at <"api-env">: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.ORGANIZATION_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

The key `.items` only gets populated when there is more than one resource that matches the lookup.

Since there is only one `ConfigMap` named `api-env` on the `default` namespace , you can access directly the data you want:

```
(lookup "v1" "configmap" "default" "api-env").data.ORGANIZATION_NAME
```

Comment: still getting `nil pointer evaluating interface {}.ORGANIZATION_NAME` switching to using `data`.